# PHP form sending blank emails

Tags: php, email

I don't have a lot of experience with PHP - I used a form generator to create this form.  The problem is that the form is sending hundreds of blank emails.  Can anyone please help me fix it?  Here's the PHP code:

```
 <?php

$where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

mail("blah@blah.com","MESSAGE: website","

Someone has submitted a message from your website!  Huzzah!

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CONTACT INFO:
" . $_POST['field_1'] . "
" . $_POST['field_2'] . " 

MESSAGE:
" . $_POST['field_3'] . " 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Also you're a stud.

");

header("Refresh: 0;url=http://www.blah.com/thanks.html");

?>
```

Comment: make sure your html form method be POST, or use $_GET or $_REQUEST on php, the $_REQUEST be the same of value of ($_POST || $_GET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just ensure that someone actually `POST`ed data through (i.e. actually used the form) you'll be good to go:

```
<?php
    $where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

        if (!$_POST['field_1'] || !$_POST['field_2'] || !$_POST['field_3']) {
            header("Location: $where_form_is");
            exit;
        }

    mail("blah@blah.com","MESSAGE: website","Someone has submitted a message from your website!  Huzzah!
    CONTACT INFO:
    " . $_POST['field_1'] . "
    " . $_POST['field_2'] . " 

    MESSAGE:
    " . $_POST['field_3'] . " 
    Also you're a stud.");

    header("Refresh: 0;url=http://www.blah.com/thanks.html");
    exit;
?>
```